# Stream of Object map in different ways based on their class

Tags: java

I need to map the ArrayList of Object to ArrayList of String based on their class in the initial arraylist.
I've tried this, but I don't think it's the best way to do it.
How could I do?

```
a.stream()
  .map(Validatore::mapToString)
  .forEach(b::add);

private static String mapToString(Object o) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  if(o instanceof JPasswordField a) return new String(a.getPassword());
  if(o instanceof JTextField a) return a.getText();
  if(o instanceof DatePicker a) return a.getDate()!=null 
     ? a.getDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")) : "";
  if(o instanceof JComboBox a) return a.getSelectedItem()!=null 
     ? a.getSelectedItem().toString() : "";
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

The aim is to simplify the method (JTextField a, JTextField b, JCombobox c, ...) through a method that uses stream to check if all fields are not empty.
I used

```
return a.stream()
                .map(Validatore::mapToString)
                .filter(String::isEmpty)
                .limit(1)
                .peek(System.out.println("Empty"))
                .findAny()
                .isEmpty();
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirements. You could use a map of converters:

```
Map<Class<?>, Function<Object,String>> converterMap = new HashMap<>();

public <T> void registerConverter(Class<T> clazz, Function<T,String> conv) {
    converterMap.put(clazz, (obj) -> conv.apply(clazz.cast(obj)));
}

{
    registerConverter(JPasswordField.class, (pw) -> new String(pw.getPassword()));
    registerConverter(JTextField.class, (txt) -> txt.getText());
    // ...
}

public String toString(Object obj) {
    Function<Object,String> conv = converterMap.get(obj.getClass());
    if (conv != null) {
        return conv.apply(obj);
    }
    return obj.toString();
}
```

You may want to deal with inheritance:

```
public String toString(Object obj) {
    Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
    while (clazz != null) {
        Function<Object,String> conv = converterMap.get(clazz);
        if (conv != null) {
            return conv.apply(obj);
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    return obj.toString();
}
```

You may also want to deal with interfaces and multiple inheritance, but that's a little trickier.

Comment: I added more information to the question. Could you help me?